# How to repeat the last : command for a visual selection instead of whole buffer?

Tags: command-line, visual-mode

Say I've done the command:

```
:g/^.\{1,50\}$/m$
```

To move all lines with 50 or less characters to the bottom of the file.

Then I realise I actually didn't want to do that for the whole file, but for example a paragraph (or for any visually selected lines). I then do `u` and `vip` to select the paragraph I want the `g` command to affect, I press `:`, and try to press `<UP>` to get the previous command, problem is that there are only commands I've done when I've been in visual mode.

How should I do this, so that I don't have to type the whole `g` command again for the visual selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred solution is

1. Select your paragraph `vip`
2. Hit `:` and then `<C-f>` OR press `q:`
3. Move up to your `:g` command and do `I'<,'>`, then `Esc`, then `<CR>`.

As mentioned in the comments, it might be handy to map this:

```
xnoremap <Leader>. q:<UP>I'<,'><Esc>$
```

Comment: This works great! I made a mapping which makes this very smooth: `xnoremap <Leader>, q:<UP>I'<,'><Esc>$`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you can't do it in general for *any* visual selection, since the ex commands operate on lines, so only for *the whole lines* which are fully *or partially* visually selected you can run such a command. E.g. you have a line 'Hello w**or**ld' with the 'or' selected, but you can't operate on the selection, which is 'or', only on the whole line 'Hello w**or**ld'

Use the automatically placed marks `'<` for the first line of the visual selection, and `'>` for the last one. The marks can be set with no visible selection (for example, if you escaped the select mode), and the command below will still work, but you can always press `gv` in the normal mode, to restore the last selection.

So the command would be

```
:'<,'> g/^.\{1,50\}$/m$
```

With the requirement to use the last command without retyping, one can use the `normal` ex command and the `@:` command from the normal mode:

```
:'<,'> normal @:
```

But I personally don't find this convenient, it seems to be quicker to invoke the command history window, find you command (if it was so long to type) edit it quickly with the '<,'> marks and run it

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand my question. Yes I know I can operate on the visual selection by just selecting some lines and typing `:`, which will automatically insert `:'<,'>` to the command line, BUT I would have to type the whole `g/^.\{1,50\}$/m$` command again after that, and that is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: @ruohola, there is a couple of suggestions in such a case

Comment: You can also expand the command register in-line. Type `:`, you get the selection markers added automatically, then type Ctrl-r followed by `:` to insert a copy of the last command line. (See `:help quote_:` for info on this and other registers and `:help c_CTRL-R` for info on what that keystroke does in command mode.)

Comment: I have that upper arrow in the command window brings the last command, if you want to ask about this, ask another question or look for the answer(better)

Answer (score 1):

You can  edit the last command to include \%V in the beginning of the pattern `g/\%Vpattern/cmd` and it will search the last visual selection.

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/241589/in-vim-how-to-search-and-replace-in-visual-selection/